# Algorithm to find count of numbers between 2 integers where digits do not repeat

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for an algorithm to find a list of numbers between two integers such that the digits in each number don't repeat?

For example, given an input of 2 and 12, the answer would be all numbers except 11. 
The naive solution would be to iterate over the numbers and check whether any digit repeats.  However, for big numbers, this approach would take a huge amount of time.

---

i need to find the count of such no.s between the given two large no.s;
Another method i thought was to take an array(a[10]) of size 10 where each index would store the frequecy of each digit of a certain no. b/w the limits,and if we get an index where freq exceeds 1,that no would be discarded.
I would repeat this for all the no.s between the limits,each time initializing the array 'a' indexes to 0.
But this method too will take huge comutation time for large inputs(like when the limits are 1 to 10^9).
I need a still better method.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Please post the code if you have tried. It is always helpful for others to answer if there is a piece of code in the question.

Comment: It's pretty obvious what the code for the naive algorithm would be. Posting it doesn't help. The question is about the algorithm not the code.

Comment: @fgb the presence of the [c] tag suggests the opposite.

Comment: @moooeeeep C is the target language, which may be relevant, but it's still a problem about the algorithm as shown by the [algorithm] tag. The algorithm the OP suggested won't work in time, as he correctly noticed, so implementing won't be a valid solution. You need to sort out the problems with the algorithm before coding.

Comment: What does your naïve algorithm look like?  I can think of several possible ways to do it, and I don't know which one is your naïve algorithm.

Comment: Wait till the Nov12 competition is over at codechef. You will get the answer of http://www.codechef.com/NOV12/problems/DDISH in tutorial.

Till that time, try to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will not give you the exact solution but will try to give you some tips on how to approach similar problems.

First of all - whenever you have a problem of the type find the count of numbers between `a` and `b` it is (almost) always easier to implement a solution that will give you the answer for  the interval `(0, x]` for a given x. For instance if you want to count the number in the interval `[a,b]` and you implement a function that returns the answer for the interval `(0,x]` for all non-negative x(say that function is `f`), then you can compute the answer for `[a,b]` as `f(b) - f(a - 1)`. Trust me this saves a lot of corner cases checking and is also usaully faster to implement.

Having said this try to think how you can count the numbers that don't have a repeating digit in the interval `(0,a]`. What I would suggest is that you compute the answer for the numbers having a fixed number of digits separately. For the numbers having less digits then a this is pretty straight forward - simply compute a variation. For the numbers with count of digits equal to our number a it is a bit trickier. I believe it is easiest to count them using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Hope this helps and hope it is not too detailed so that you still have to solve something on your own.

Comment: :if you could please explain you algo with an example;i am not getting it("compute the answer for the numbers having a fixed number of digits separately. For the numbers having less digits then a this is pretty straight forward - simply compute a variation")

Comment: How many numbers with different digits and 4 digits do you have? 9 options for the first digit(all but 0), 9 for the second one(all but the one already selected), 8 for the third(all digits except the two already selected) and 7 for the last digit(try to figure that out). Similarly the 5 digit numbers are 9*9*8*7*6 Got it now?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an algorithm to count permutations of digits. Given integer A with m digits and integer B with n digits (m >= n), you need to:

```
1. for i = m; i < n; i++
    if i < 10, choose i digits out of 10
    Permutate through digits of length i (if i=m, discard permutations that are less than A)

2. Permutate digits of length n, as long as result isn't larger than B.
```

Choosing and permutating are combinatorial operations, you can easily find a mathematical formulae for them (recursive versions are available as well), e.g. here is a link describing permutations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

The complexity will be O((n+1)!)

Comment: He only wants to count these numbers. This can be done in O(n^2) which apparently is way better then what you suggest.

Comment: He specifically stated that he needs a **list** of numbers and even gave an example.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have seen this problem elsewhere and there you were only asked to give the number. If you are asked to print the whole list, not much of an improvement can be made to the brute force algorithm.

Comment: @izomorphius Agree, my suggestion is just a bit better but it's due to the nature of the problem. Anyway, in the title it's indeed stated to count the numbers. Either the title or the body of the question should be edited by the author

Comment: @izomorphius,@icepack:sorry for the ambiguous statement.i just need the count of no.s not the list